# How to show the week number on the Windows system tray calendar?

Tags: windows-7, calendar, notification-area

I am using Windows 7, and sometimes I would like to check the current week number from the calendar. However, by default, the Windows system tray calendar does not show the week numbers.

Is it possible to make the week numbers visible in the system tray calendar?

[image: Windows System Tray calendar]

Comment: You'll need some app to hook into Explorer and add that info there (meaning it has to keep running in the background), and so far I've not seen anything that fits the bill (doesn't mean it doesn't exist, of course).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Solutions including some sort of third-party applications are also welcome. I did also some Googling on this topic, but did not find any useful information. It's pretty strange that Microsoft did not include an option to show the week numbers by default.

Comment: Microsoft took the time to add a useless analog clock, but didn't add week numbers... go figure.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got the week numbers using the T-Clock (suggested by Mikal Madsen).

Here is what I did:

1. Downloaded the [T-Clock (binaries)](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock/releases) (the file T-Clock.zip)
2. Extracted the Zip
3. Ran Clock64.exe
   [image]
4. Miscellaneous -> Checked
   "Use T-Clock's calendar" and "Show week numbers" 
   [image]
5. Pressed Apply ->
   OK (now the system clock changed)
6. Left clicked the system
   clock/calendar (Unchecked the "Always ask before opening this file", and pressed Run)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now the calendar shows three months and the week numbers!

### Note:

Note that at different parts of the world (USA, EU), the week numbers are defined differently. For example, in EU the first week of the year is the first week with at least 4 days. The default in T-Clock (2.4.0.) is the USA settings which means that Week 1 is the week containing January 1st. The behavior can be changed in the T-Clock settings, under Miscellaneous.

Comment: Tested this on Windows 10 also. Works perfectly!

Comment: personally I would have extended @MikalMadsen's answer

Answer (score 13):

T-clock is free and does what you want. Easy to set up and customize and comes with excellent instruction document. Installed it myself and set it up now in Windows 7 - works great.

https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock

Comment: I wouldn't call this spam, but I'd suggest a good answer would cover *how* you would set this up to do what the OP wants rather than blindly suggest a product recommendation. A good answer here is about the *process* not the product.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'm pretty new to this, didn't really know what to say, wanted to just make a quick response since this was during work hours and I wanted to get back to it but still give something to the common good while I had it up. I will improve my comment, thanks a lot  for the constructive criticism.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Not intending to start a discussion, but I find the recommendations on this forum VERY important. I don't just download every app. Info on how to setup is less important, I would be able to figure this out myself, esp. for such a well-constructed app as t-clock.

Answer (score 6):

With [T-clock](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock/releases) you can get the week number to show in the system tray:

1. Download and unzip
2. Start Clock64.exe
3. Time Format -> Check the "Advanced clock format" box
4. Add 'Wi' (without quotes) somewhere in the format (see example below)
5. Press "Apply"

An example format (that happens to be the one I'm using):

H:nn w.Wi\n yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0):

There's a terribly expensive solution - Anuko World Clock: https://www.anuko.com/world_clock/
At the time of writing it costs $25, which is a bit of an overkill.

There's also http://www.trayday.com/, it's also quite expensive and does not seem to be maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There's also TimeTray http://www.olivertacke.de/it/time-tray/; it's not polished for Windows 7 and higher (read: gray background color), but it shows the CW as an status icon.